Low-budget fantasy movie scene where a sorcerer's apprentice creates a banana but has no idea what it is
This was a movie I rented on VHS, back in the late 1980s or early 1990s. It was a quasi-medieval swords-and-sorcery fantasy, clearly made with a very low budget. It's tone was mostly serious, but sprinkled with humor. I can't really remember any of the actual story, but there is one very brief scene that sticks in my memory. A sorcerer and his apprentice (I think that's what they were) were hungry, so the sorcerer told the apprentice to try and conjure a sausage from thin air, both as an exercise and as a way to get something to eat. The apprentice tried, but he got it wrong and created a banana instead. Being from medieval Europe, neither of them had ever seen a banana. They both stared at it, and the apprentice said "What is it?" Then the sorcerer said something like "Don't know. It's passing strange. Better throw it away."
Can anyone identify this movie?

this may help ... https://imsdb.com/

Wizards of the Lost Kingdom II (1989).

The aging and incompetent wizard Caedmon is tasked by Grand-Wizard Vanir with training the young farmhand Tyor in the ways of magic, as he is the Chosen One, destined to free the three kingdoms from the three evil sorcerers that rule them with the power of three magical objects.

About half an hour into the film -- just after Caedmon and Tyor encounter Princess Amathea in a forest -- a hungry Tyor attempts to transform a stick into a sausage but it turns into a banana instead.

CAEDMON: What is that?
TYOR: I don't know.
CAEDMON: Don't eat it. Throw it away. It's passing strange.





Holy smoke! The special effects are bad, and they know it, so they toss in some funny stuff. The guy falling from the wall onto the mattress is priceless Hollywood silliness. If I had time to watch this, I don't know whether I'd like it or not. I know my girlfriend would say it's stupid.

YouTube suggested I watch the trailer for the original Wizards of the Lost Kingdom next. Not only does it look just as cheesy, but there's a remarkable amount of reused footage between the two trailers.

This film reuses footage from several earlier films, including The Warrior and the Sorceress (starring David Carradine) and Barbarian Queen (starring Lana Clarkson). Some new scenes with Carradine and Clarkson were also shot to serve as connective tissue between the plot of this film and the reused footage. Carradine appears to be wearing a wig in the new footage, presumably because his natural hair no longer matched the style he had in the older footage from a few years prior.
